# Number of ways to multiply n matrices?

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming

I keep thinking about this problem in terms of factorials. That is at first you can choose between n matrices, then n-1, then n-2 and so forth.

Which gives you $n*(n-1)*(n-2) *... *1 = n!$  ways to multiply.

This is incorrect.

Ive seen that the correct way to set up this problem is to have $P(n)$ which defines the number of ways to multiply n matrices. Then we get

$$P(n) = P(1)P(n-1) + P(2)P(n-2) + ... + P(n-1)P(1)$$

Can someone please explain to me why it wont work here to think in terms of factorials, which is what I would do in simpler combinatorial problems. And also explain why the latter approach works.

I cannot wrap my head around this and distingush between the two.

Comment: You were right the first time, it is $n!$. It depends only in which order you put them in, and $n!$ is the number of permutations of $n!$ elements

Comment: The displayed equation refers to the parentheses problem, which counts the number of ways you can carry out the multiplications *when the order of the terms is fixed*, e.g., $A(B(CD))$, $A((BC)D)$, $(AB)(CD)$, $(A(BC))D$, and $((AB)C)D$.

Comment: From some perspective, there is only one way of multiplying $ABCD$ through $(AB)(CD)$ but not two, since multiplying $AB$ first or $CD$ first or even parallely does not matter. Compare with Barry's comment above, if $(AB)(CD)$ were counted twice instead, then there would be indeed $6=3!$ ways.

Comment: @peterwhy, good point!